# UITableView Selection Issue

Tags: ios, iphone

I have UITableView with three sections. And  I have a radio buttons in each cell of each section. I need to select one radio button in each sections at a time. That means I need to select 3rd cells radio button in section1 and 1st cells radio button in next section and so on. Bt now the problem is if i select one radio button in one section and if i try to select other cells in other section, the previous selected radio button is replaced with the newly selected radio button.And I add the radio buttons as cells accessoryView. Please help me.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
   if (cell==nil) {
        NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"nib" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.my_label.text=@"";
    cell.labelKWD.hidden=TRUE;
    UIButton *newRadioButton;
    newRadioButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    newRadioButton.frame = CGRectMake(30, 0, 15, 14.5);
    [newRadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_button_b.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [newRadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_button_a.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    cell.accessoryView = newRadioButton;
    if ([indexPath isEqual:selectedIndex]) {
        newRadioButton.selected = YES;
    }
    else {
        newRadioButton.selected = NO;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        selectedIndex = indexPath;
        [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: please add your code. @hilaj

Comment: @interface class : UIView<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndex;
      
}

Comment: please add your code in question. where is problem in code. @hilaj

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
if (cell==nil) {
            NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"nib name" owner:self options:nil];
            cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell .my_label .text=@"";
        cell.labelKWD.hidden=TRUE;
        UIButton *newRadioButton;
        newRadioButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        newRadioButton.frame = CGRectMake(30, 0, 15, 14.5);

Comment: [newRadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_button_b.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [newRadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_button_a.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        cell.accessoryView = newRadioButton;
        
        
        if ([indexPath isEqual:selectedIndex]) {
            
            newRadioButton.selected = YES;
            
        }
        else {
            newRadioButton.selected = NO;
            
        }
        
        return cell;
    }

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
        selectedIndex = indexPath;
        [tableView reloadData];
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an `NSMutableArray` for the selected indexPaths. Your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will be something like this then.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if([self.selectedIndexArray containsObject:indexPath]){
        [self.selectedIndexArray removeObject:indexPath];
    }
    else{
        [self.selectedIndexArray addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` where you change the selection will be something like this:

```
if([self.selectedIndexArray containsObject:indexPath]){
    newRadioButton.selected = YES;
}
else{
    newRadioButton.selected = NO;
}
```

Comment: but I have sections in tableview. Then it will not work properly.

Comment: You will be using `NSIndexPath` so this will work fine. Because `NSIndexPath` stores both section and row value.

Comment: Just try implementing this, and you will know it works fine. Don't forget to initialize `selectedIndexArray` in `viewDidLoad:` of your view controller.